# How to get a string out of another class

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm super new to java and i need to know how to get a string out of another class i have.

The Class That Needs The String:

```
package future.blue.fun.tasks;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;
import org.inventivetalent.glow.GlowAPI;

public class RainbowTask extends BukkitRunnable {

Player player = //I NEED THE STRING HERE;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        GlowAPI.setGlowing(player, GlowAPI.Color.BLUE, player);
        GlowAPI.setGlowing(player, GlowAPI.Color.RED, player);
        GlowAPI.setGlowing(player, GlowAPI.Color.GREEN, player);
        GlowAPI.setGlowing(player, GlowAPI.Color.YELLOW, player);
    }
}
```

The Class That Has The String:

```
package future.blue.fun.commands;


import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitScheduler;
import org.inventivetalent.glow.GlowAPI;

import future.blue.fun.main;




public class SetGlow implements CommandExecutor {





    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] arg) {
        //THE STRING I NEED
        Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(arg[1]);.....

        return false;
    }

}
```

Can some one help me with this?

More info for bukkit coders:

I'm using spigot 1.10.2

All i want is to loop a code with configurable ticks between etch command

I need the looping code to be run unlimited times

I need this code to be executed by a command in another class and use a string from that class.

Comment: i fail to see any String. Aswell as `//I NEED THE STRING HERE;` doesn´t really make any sense when you have `Player player`

Comment: You are super new to coding, so your first attempt at it is to code something for minecraft?

Comment: What rabbit guy is telling you: maybe you first spend some weeks learning at least the absolute basics of Java, before trying to go for an **advanced** topic? Consider learning to crawl before trying to do hurdle racing.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Your String and Player confusion ...

I think you are dealing with access modifiers there are four access modifiers in java

1. Default
2. Private
3. Public and
4. Protected

Default method or attribute can be accessed only from classes within a package. Private can be accessed only within a class. Protected can be accessed from within a class and with inheritance.

As i see in your code the class RainbowTask placed in the package future.blue.fun.tasks; and you are trying to access a local variable called player from SetGlow class which is found in the package future.blue.fun.commands;

So you have to make an attribute player to be a class variable instead of local.
and you have to import package future.blue.fun.commands.SetGlow; in RainbowTask or you have to make them in one package

lets seee what i make

```js
//RainbowTask


package future.blue.fun.tasks;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;
import org.inventivetalent.glow.GlowAPI;
import future.blue.fun.commands.SetGlow;

public class RainbowTask extends BukkitRunnable {

Player player;
SetGlow sg=new SetGlow();

 public void gerPlayer(){
  player=sg.player;
 }
 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        GlowAPI.setGlowing(player, GlowAPI.Color.BLUE, player);
        GlowAPI.setGlowing(player, GlowAPI.Color.RED, player);
        GlowAPI.setGlowing(player, GlowAPI.Color.GREEN, player);
        GlowAPI.setGlowing(player, GlowAPI.Color.YELLOW, player);
    }
}






//SetGlow

package future.blue.fun.commands;


import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitScheduler;
import org.inventivetalent.glow.GlowAPI;

import future.blue.fun.main;




public class SetGlow implements CommandExecutor {


public Player player;


    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] arg) {
        player = Bukkit.getPlayer(arg[1]);.....
        return false;
    }

}
```

NB:- You have to be sure onCommand method is called before the we assign the value otherwise it shows you Null Pointer Exception.